# jQuery updating elements added on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My code is not working, i think because elements are added *on the fly*:

```
var tooltip = $('<div/>').insertAfter('.trigger').addClass('tooltip');
var tname = $('<span/>').addClass('tname').text('(...)');
tooltip.html(tname.html()):

// Ajax call
success: function() {
  tname.html('success'); // not working
  $('.tooltip').find('.tname').html('success'); // not working
  $('.tname').html('success'); // not working
}
```

Comment: dynamic insertion of elements may not be the reason, show the html you are dealing with

Comment: You first three lines boil down to `tooltip = $('<span class="tname">(...)</span>');` and you're nuking the div/class you originally added to tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because you are not inserting the `tname` element into the DOM. See this fix below:

```
var tooltip = $('<div/>').insertAfter('.trigger').addClass('tooltip');
var tname = $('<span/>').addClass('tname').text('(...)');
tooltip.html("");
tooltip.append(tname);

// Ajax call
success: function() {
  tname.html('success'); // should work
  $('.tooltip').find('.tname').html('success'); // should work
  $('.tname').html('success'); // should work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not inserting the span into the DOM.

```
//                                                       append to some element
var tname = $('<span/>').addClass('tname').text('(...)').appendTo(tooltip);
```

Only then you can use selectors to find the element and do something with it.

Comment: tooltip div is added to the dom (assuming .trigger exist somewhere), and then the span replaces the div completely. Weird construct, but SHOULD be in the dom somewhere.

Comment: @Marc B: But the class `tname` is not returned by `.html()` (only the inner HTML) so the class won't be added to the DOM, and the selectors with `.tname` won't work.